# Scala data model for read-only entities

Tags: oop, scala

I'm working on modeling entities that will be persisted in a DB. Using a User entity as an example, I'd like to work with them in this way:

```
val userBeforePersisting = new User("Joe", "joe@gmail.com")

// DB access code (where rs is a ResultSet)
val foundUser = new User(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("email"))
```

I'd like to use the same User code (i.e. minimize code duplication), while having two types of users:

1. Pre-persisted users do not have an ID
2. Persisted users retrieved from the DB have an ID

I'd like to enforce this as strictly as possible at compile-time.

I'd like to be able to treat all Users the same, except if I try and get an ID from an un-persisted User, an error will be raised or it would not compile.

I'd like to avoid having to make separate classes like this

```
class NewUser(val name: String, val email: String)
class PersistedUser(val id: Long, val name: String, val email: String)
```

I don't like this solution because of the code duplication (name and email fields).

Here's kind of what I'm thinking:

```
class User(val id: Long, val name: String, val email: String) {
  this(name: String, email: String) = this(0l, name, email)
  this(id: Long, name: String, email: String) = this(id, name, email)
}
```

But then my un-persisted users have an `id` of `0l`.

Here's another approach:

```
trait User {
  val name: String
  val email: String
}

class NewUser(val name: String, val email: String) extends User

class PersistedUser(val id: Long, val name: String, val email: String) extends User
```

This gives me the compile-time checks that I'd like. I'm not sure if there are any draw-backs to this.

Maybe I could try something like this:

```
class User(val name: String, val email: String)
trait Persisted { val id: Long }
class PersistedUser(val id: Long, val name: String, val email: String)
  extends User(name, email)
  with Persisted
```

Any thoughts to these approaches? I've never done it this way, so I'm not sure if I understand all the consequences.

Comment: What do you not like about the last approach?  Is it the minor code duplication where `val name: String, val email: String` appears twice?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a possible use of `Option`.

```
class User(val id: Option[Long], val name: String, val email: String)
```

So persisted users have an `id` of `Some(id)` whereas non-persisted users have `None`.

As a convenience, you could grant `id` a default value of `None`:

```
class User(val id: Option[Long] = None, val name: String, val email: String)

// When you have an id...
val foundUser = new User(Some(rs.getLong("id")), 
    name = rs.getString("name"), email = rs.getString("email"))

// When you don't
val userBeforePersisting = new User(name = "Joe", email = "joe@gmail.com")

// However this will throw a runtime error:
val idThatDoesntExist: Long = userBeforePersisting.id.get
```

This should also work with your multi-constructor example:

```
class User(val id: Option[Long], val name: String, val email: String) {
  def this(name: String, email: String) = this(None, name, email)
  def this(id: Long, name: String, email: String) = this(Some(id), name, email)
}
```

I thought `Option` might make sense because you'd like to express *in the same class* that a certain field can either have a value or not. The only other way seems to be to have *two* classes (possibly one inheriting from the other) with only one having an `id` field.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Faiz. I had considered Options, and I think it's a good approach. The thing I don't like about this approach is that most of my handling of Users is of persisted user and I'd like to avoid all the .get calls. I did give you an up-vote because it's a solid solution.

Comment: @three_cups_of_java I see - well, I guess idiomatic usage of `Option` usually eschews `.get` in favor of `foreach`/`map`/`filter` etc - but I understand now that you'd like a `PersistedUser` class where you take for granted that the `id` field represents a real id as persisted.